# Custom HTML Button not working when dragging mouse off button

Tags: javascript, html, button, dom-events

I have an HTML Button that wraps an image tag and has an `onmouseup` and `onmousedown` handler defined. When the button is down the image changes to the pressed image and when it's up it changes to the up image. The issue is if the user drags their mouse off of the button while it's down, the `onmouseup` event is never called so the image stays in the pressed state. Here's an example of what's going on. Try clicking the button and dragging off of it: http://jsfiddle.net/gsingh93/ubyV8/5/

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call mouseUp() when the mouse leaves the button:

```
onmouseout="mouseUp();"
```

Comment: You are asking how to turn the image back if the mouseup is happened outside the button. And this does not do what you wanted.

Comment: This does not even fix your problem. As you move the cursor out of the button, it will turn back. (not when mouseup)

Comment: Derek - this is the problem I tried to solve: "The issue is if the user drags their mouse off of the button while it's down, the onmouseup event is never called so the image stays in the pressed state". My solution fixes this. So does yours, but I bet I can type mine faster.

Comment: It turned back when the user did not even release the button.

Comment: You need to have mouseUp for both handlers. That should probably be added to the answer, although I figured that out pretty quickly. http://jsfiddle.net/gsingh93/ubyV8/21/

Comment: @gsingh2011 - It is because you are dragging the image. Try http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ubyV8/22/ `Code = break` It will not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `window` as the target:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
    document.getElementById("image").src = "http://www.clogsmusic.com/padma/redCircle50x50.gif";
    window.onmouseup = function(){
        document.getElementById("image").src = "http://creativeenergyblog.files.wordpress.com/2008/05/blue-circle.jpg?w=50&h=50";
    }
});
```

**WORKING DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/XTLJ6/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it! I got rid of the image and make the image the background of the button instead. Also I implemented a condition onmouseout() call to take care of your issue. Take a look. Up vote if you like!

http://jsfiddle.net/ubyV8/19/